# Making a jar from a Eclipse RCP app

Tags: java, jar, eclipse-rcp

how can i make a runnable Jar from an RCP app (e.g. the mail template).
In the MAINFEST.MF under exporting -> Export Wizard i can export the project as a JAR File.
When i try

```
java -jar mail_1.0.0.201301161746.jar
```

it says

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from mail_1.0.0.201301161746.jar
```

cause there is no Main-Class:xyzclass entry in there (cause it's a rcp app).

So what do i add there or how can i make it runnable?

Comment: Why do you need a single jar?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you need to.
Once you have your application configured/developed/branded you can export it as an eclipse product.
To do this Right click the project > Export > Plug-in development > Eclipse product
You are going to need a configuration file to do that.
You can create it by clicking the new project button on Eclipse > Plug-in development > Product Configuration I suggest you give the file the name config.ini.

For more information pls refer:
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fproduct_editor%2Fconfiguration.htm

Comment: Thank you, but i already have a product (and a exported exe). So there is no way to export it as a single executable jar file?

Answer (score 1):

An RCP app is running in [Equinox](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/) (an implementation of OSGi), hence a one-jar export is not possible.

The entire notion of OSGi is to provide a **modular** architecture.